# Reuse variables in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, global-variables

I can't understand how variables and scopes are supposed to be used. Here there is my failed attempt to **re**use a variable defined inside a function:

```
def basedOnVariableFunctAffectingVar(a):
    v = tf.get_variable("nameV2",
                        dtype=tf.float64,
                        initializer=tf.constant([0.0,1],
                                                dtype=tf.float64))
    aa = tf.constant(np.array([a,a]))
    t = v + aa
    v.assign(t)
    return t
```

And then I call the function:

```
with tf.variable_scope("Scope0"):
    res1 = basedOnVariableFunctAffectingVar(2.0)

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    result1 = session.run(res1)

    with tf.variable_scope("Scope0",
                           reuse=True):
        a = tf.get_variable("nameV2", dtype=tf.float64)
    print(session.run(a))
    print(result1)
```

Quite surprisingly the output is:

> [0. 1.] [2. 3.]

I expected

> [2. 3.] [2. 3.]

Thanks to anyone clarifying the concepts of variable and scopes in TF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code above nobody evaluates the assignment. This fixes:

```
def basedOnVariableFunctAffectingVar(a):
    v = tf.get_variable("nameV2",
                        dtype=tf.float64,
                        initializer=tf.constant([0.0,1],
                                                dtype=tf.float64))
    aa = tf.constant(np.array([a,a]))
    t = v.assign(v + aa)
return t
```

The result of assigning a variable has to be evaluated and in the function of the question the evaluation is not in the subgraph needed to run res1.